# Transform an "empty" XML with XSLT or: How to use an XML Template?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Is it possible to transform an "empty" or non-existing XML into another XML with XSLT?

What I'm trying to do is just fill in a couple of parameters into a template XML.

Say, my XML looks like:

```
<someTag value="someValue">someValueOrOther</someTag>
<otherTag>dynamicValue</otherTag>
```

How do I fill these values?

I could generate an empty XML Document and transform it (and just disregard the input), but this seems ugly. I'd rather use some sort of template.

Also, I'm no fan of doing things like this in code with JAXB:

```
myDoc.getSomeElement().getSomethingNested().getEvenMoreNested().setFooElement("someVal");
```

Ideally, I would have a static XML-file with placeholders or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

One (little-known) approach to this is to use the "simplified stylesheet" syntax.

Use a stylesheet like this:

```
<root xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <fixedTag>fixed content</fixedTag>
    <someTag><xsl:value-of select="*/param1"/></someTag>
    <otherTag><xsl:value-of select="*/param2"/></otherTag>
</root>
```

and a source document like this:

```
<params>
  <param1>Variable content 1</param1>
  <param2>Variable content 2</param2>
</params>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the OP needs to build an XML document to use as input, when building an XML document in Java code is what he seems to try to avoid in the first place?

Comment: I thought they want to pass the variable content as parameter/s at runtime. This doesn't seem to be possible - at least not with a Saxon processor (libxslt seems to be more flexible in this regard).

Comment: Possibly (to both of you). I just thought I'd throw it in the ring, since I don't really know what the underlying requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a template XML document such as:

```
<root>
    <fixedTag>fixed content</fixedTag>
    <someTag>required placeholder</someTag>
    <otherTag>required placeholder</otherTag>
</root>
```

you can use a stylesheet such as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="some">some dynamic content</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="other">other dynamic content</xsl:param>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="someTag/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="$some"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="otherTag/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="$other"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <fixedTag>fixed content</fixedTag>
   <someTag>some dynamic content</someTag>
   <otherTag>other dynamic content</otherTag>
</root>
```

Note that processing a "dummy" XML document that contains nothing but:

```
<root/>
```

and maintaining the entire template within the stylesheet would not be much different.

---

### Edit:

To add an attribute to `someTag` you could make your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="some">some dynamic content</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="other">other dynamic content</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="value">dynamic value</xsl:param>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="someTag">
    <someTag value="{$value}"><xsl:value-of select="$some"/></someTag>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="otherTag/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="$other"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note this would work without making any changes to the template XML. IMHO, you may be over-complicating this by forcing yourself to manage two templates in parallel, one in the stylesheet itself and one as an external XML document.

Comment: It's worth noting that this fails when the "dynamic" tags are completely empty in the template. They must always contain some sort of dummy text.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, that's why they are **not** empty in my example. I'll edit their content to make this more clear.

Comment: @Davio Not quite the same way. You cannot match just the *value* of an attribute, it's not a node.

Comment: So how do I dynamically replace the value of an attribute?

Comment: @Davio I suggest you edit your question and include an attribute in your example.